# Eclipse does not show non-existent Maven properties

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, properties, m2e

HI I am using Eclipse Mars and have Maven Project then I have configuration like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-javadoc-plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <skip>${javadocs.skip}</skip>
        <!-- avoiding javadoc warnings caused by Mojo annotations -->
        <tagletArtifacts>
            <tagletArtifact>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-plugin-tools-javadoc</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
            </tagletArtifact>
        </tagletArtifacts>
        <footer>Generated ${maven.build.timestamp}</footer>
        <!-- Do not fail if there is docs errors. -->
        <additionalparam>${additionalparam}</additionalparam>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But the property `additionalparam` is not specified but the Eclipse does not show warning message.

**Question**: Is there way to enable warnings in Eclipse for Maven pom?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to have a warning for this scenario in Eclipse.

Below a screenshot of the Maven/Eclipse integration and which types of warnings you could configure:

[image]

Taken from *Window* > *Preferences* > *Maven*

---

Also note: in some cases an non existing property may be consumed (configured in some plugin) on purpose. Some reasonable cases:

- The property is supposed to be passed from command line, ignored if empty (non existing)
- The property would be populated only by a profile, [activated](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html#Details_on_profile_activation) upon something (a variable, an OS, a Java version)
- The property is only set by a certain component, for example the Continuous Integration server

Comment: I did what you said but nothing happens. There is no warning in the javaDoc plugin.

Comment: I didn't say you need to configure something to get the warnings, I actually said you cannot get this type of warning (in case a propery is used but doesn't exist) and I showed why (the option is not present)